# Email never received If there is a URL inside message body - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I try to send an email with codeigniter library. Simple plain email working perfect but as soon as I put any URL like www.abc.com, codeigniter gives message that email sent but I never received. I change the mailtype to HTML with no luck.

Any ideas please.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['priority'] = "1";
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from("myemail@gmail.com", 'TS');
$this->email->to("myemail@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject('Test Email');

$txt_site_name = "www.google.com";

$this->email->message("This is test email with link --> ".$txt_site_name);

if($this->email->send())
{
    echo "The email has been sent";
}else{
    echo "Could not send the email";
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please see the code above.

Comment: The code looks fine. If `$this->email->send()` is returning true, then it is probably not a codeigniter problem. May sound silly, but have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Yes I did check the spam and even i try to change TO email for any other server but no luck.

Comment: The code is in working condition, tested it.

Comment: Dear Niloy.. Did you get the link in your email? If yes why I can't. I am testing it on godaddy server. Is there any configuration for godaddy?